# eBay Trading API - calling structure in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ebay-api, trading

I am trying to call eBay API through Delphi. After long time searching through Google and StackOverflow, I can get "GeteBayTime" (Shopping API) and "findItemsByKeywords" (Finding API) work properly now.

When I started to test with Trading API, I have no idea where and how to insert seller's account info (userid and password). My first program for trading API is shown below and it is started with API call "GetSellingManagerSoldListings".

Can any one show me some clue to make Trading API work? And if anything else needs to be added to HTTP.header or Paramters?

Thanks.

```
procedure TForm1.btnEBayGetSoldListClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sURL, sResponse, sEndpoint: String;
  jResult: TJSONObject;
  sCallName, sSiteID, sVersion: String;
  k: Integer;
  sParameters: String;
  sHeaders: TStringList;
  sRequestBody: TStringStream;
begin
  // Trading API
  sEndpoint := 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';

  sCallName := 'GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest';
  sSiteID := '15';
  sVersion := '967';
  sAppID := 'myAppID';
  sDevID := 'myDevID';
  sToken : 'myToken';    // OAuth Token?

  sURL := sEndpoint
       + '?callname=' + sCallName
       + '&siteid=' + '15';

  sHeaders := TStringList.Create;
  with sHeaders do begin
    Add('X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL' + '=' + sVersion);
    Add('X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME' + '=' + sDevID);
    Add('X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' + '=' + sAppID);
    Add('X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME' + '=' + sCertID);
    Add('X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME' + '=' + sCallName);
    Add('X-EBAY-API-SITEID' + '=' + sSiteID);
  end;

  objHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';

  with objHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders do begin
    Clear;
    AddStdValues(sHeaders);
  end;
  sHeaders.Free;

  sParameters := '<GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'
               + '  <RequesterCredentials>'
               + '    <eBayAuthToken>' + sToken + '</eBayAuthToken>'
               + '   <Filter>' + 'PaidNotShipped' + '</Filter>'
               + '  </RequesterCredentials>'
               + '</GetItemTransactionsRequest>';
  sRequestBody := TStringStream.Create(sParameters, TEncoding.UTF8);

  try
    sResponse := objHTTP.Post(sURL, sRequestBody);
    memHTML.Lines.Add(sResponse);
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
  except
    sResponse := objHTTP.ResponseText;
    memHTML.Lines.Add(sResponse);
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? Are you getting an error back from eBay? If so, what does it say exactly? Did you read the [GetSellingManagerSoldListings](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellingManagerSoldListings.html) and [Working with Selling Manager](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Listings-SellingManager.html) documentation?

Comment: Did you notice that your XML is malformed? You open it with `<GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>` but close it with `</GetItemTransactionsRequest>` instead of `</GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>`

Comment: Many thanks to Remy Lebeau. I got error says not matched request but I can't find it at all. Let me correct this mistake and test it again. I read those documents but can't understand them completely -> such a stupid guy as me.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I pasted error code as an answer, would you please take your time to have a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go: Complete working GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest SOAP envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <NS1:RequesterCredentials xmlns:NS1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <eBayAuthToken xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">EbayToken</eBayAuthToken>
        <NS1:Credentials>
            <AppId xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">xxx</AppId>
            <DevId xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">xxx</DevId>
            <AuthCert xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">xxx</AuthCert>
        </NS1:Credentials>
    </NS1:RequesterCredentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
        <ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
        <Version>945</Version>
        <Search>
            <SearchType>SaleRecordID</SearchType>
            <SearchValue>xxx</SearchValue>
        </Search>
        <Archived>false</Archived>
        <SaleDateRange>
            <TimeFrom>2018-08-12T17:59:32.939+02:00</TimeFrom>
            <TimeTo>2018-11-05T14:59:32.940+01:00</TimeTo>
        </SaleDateRange>
    </GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

You may omit "search" tags to get full listing.
Most of the trading api requests work this way.

Simplest way to do it in delphi:

Just put THTTPReqResp from WebServices tab on the form instead of TidHTTP, set url (THTTPReqResp1.URL) and run  with THTTPReqResp1.Execute(const DataMsg: String; Resp: TStream); where DataMsg is provided SOAP envelope and response is saved to TStream (e.g TStringStream). You may also need to set InvokeOptions -> soIgnoreInvalidCerts in some cases.

Although it is possible to "assemble" request the way You did, i'd recomend to use WSDL wizard, import [EBAY WSDL](https://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl) use  [WSDL Pruner Tool](https://developer.ebay.com/cms/files/tools/pruner.zip)  to cut less important functions  (to avoid "E2491 Maximum VIRDEF count exceeded; check for recursion") and proceed with auto-generated unit.

Comment: Thanks to Vancalar.
The real problem for me is: I don't know how to convert those XML to Delphi code for TidHTTP.Post.
I am still digging in eBay documents and now I want to make sure if EbayToken/AppID/DevID is linked to a seller account, not any developer guy?

Comment: James: EbayToken is linked to Seller, the rest identifies developer.

Comment: I edited my answer to include simplest possible example of usage pure SOAP with Delphi.

Comment: Thanks to Vancalrar. You clarified my question about EbayToken. I will have a try with your sample code.

Comment: Vancalar: You mentioned 'it is possible to "assemble" request the way'. Could you please show me simple sample for this? I would like to learn another solution to do same job.

Comment: Well if You asked  e.g. "How to communicate with EBAY using WSDL importer", i could answer this. You must realize, that SO is rather glossary (QA like) than discussion forums. The questions and answers SHOULD provide easy to find in search engines problems and solutions. If You won't understand this, this community might seem rather harsh for You :) So please formulate apropriate question and i will gladly explain how to use "proper" tools for the job :)

Comment: Thank you for your kindly comments. After I got your great help for eBay API and now I am doing many tests for different functions. It makes me busy and happy to get more experience and better understanding about API. I will prepare my next question properly before I commit it.