# soapenv:Server.userException -> error from eBay Trading API GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest

Tags: delphi, ebay-api

Thanks for Vancalar's advice and XML codes (refer to: [eBay Trading API - calling structure in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154983/ebay-trading-api-calling-structure-in-delphi)), I made a test programs as below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sSOAP: String;
  sCallName, sSiteID, sVersion: String;
  sResponseBody: TStringStream;
  xDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  sCallName := 'GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest';
  sSiteID := '15';                       // 15 for Australia
  sVersion := '945';

  sSOAP := '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
        + '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"'
        + '  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"'
        + '  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
        + '  <SOAP-ENV:Header>'
        + '    <NS1:RequesterCredentials xmlns:NS1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'
        + '      <eBayAuthToken xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sToken + '</eBayAuthToken>'
        + '      <NS1:Credentials>'
        + '        <AppId xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sAppID + '</AppId>'
        + '        <DevId xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sDevID + '</DevId>'
        + '        <AuthCert xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sCertID + '</AuthCert>'
        + '      </NS1:Credentials>'
        + '    </NS1:RequesterCredentials>'
        + '  </SOAP-ENV:Header>'
        + '  <SOAP-ENV:Body>'
        + '    <GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'
        + '      <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>'
        + '      <ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>'
        + '      <Version>945</Version>'
        {
        + '      <Search>'
        + '        <SearchType>SaleRecordID</SearchType>'
        + '        <SearchValue>' + '1981' + '</SearchValue>'
        + '      </Search>'
        }
        + '    <Archived>false</Archived>'
        + '    <SaleDateRange>'
        + '      <TimeFrom>2018-11-05T17:59:32.939+02:00</TimeFrom>'
        + '      <TimeTo>2018-11-06T23:59:59.940+01:00</TimeTo>'
        + '    </SaleDateRange>'
        + '  </GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>'
        + '</SOAP-ENV:Body>';

  objHttpReqResp.URL := 'https://api.ebay.com/wsapi';

  sResponseBody := TStringStream.Create();
  try
    objHttpReqResp.Execute(sSOAP, sResponseBody);

    xDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    xDoc.LoadFromStream(sResponseBody);
    xDoc.SaveToFile('XML_Output.txt');

    memHTML.Lines.LoadFromFile('XML_Output.txt');
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
  except
    memHTML.Lines.Add('Error happened!');
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
  end;
end;
```

Returned result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.</faultstring>
            <detail/>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Does it mean that:

1. User information has mistake (Token/AppID/DevID/CertID)?
2. or My code has issue which mixed some parameters?

Any advice?
sToken is Seller's eBay token and it is just applied from Developer.ebay.com.

Thanks.

#

Program is updated as below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sXML: String;
  sCallName, sSiteID, sVersion: String;
  sResponseBody: TStringStream;
  xDoc: IXMLDocument;
  sSaleNo: String;
begin
  sCallName := 'GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest';
  sSiteID := '15';
  sVersion := '945';
  sSaleNo := '2000';

  sXML := '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
        + '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"'
        + '  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"'
        + '  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
        + '  <SOAP-ENV:Header>'
        + '    <NS1:RequesterCredentials xmlns:NS1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'
        + '      <eBayAuthToken xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sToken + '</eBayAuthToken>'
        + '      <NS1:Credentials>'
        + '        <AppId xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sAppID + '</AppId>'
        + '        <DevId xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sDevID + '</DevId>'
        + '        <AuthCert xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + sCertID + '</AuthCert>'
        + '      </NS1:Credentials>'
        + '    </NS1:RequesterCredentials>'
        + '  </SOAP-ENV:Header>'
        + '  <SOAP-ENV:Body>'
        + '    <GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'
        + '      <Archived>false</Archived>'
        + '      <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>'
        + '      <Filter>PaidNotShipped</Filter>'
        + '      <ErrorLanguage>en_AU</ErrorLanguage>'
        + '      <Version>' + sVersion + '</Version>'
        + '    </GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>'
        + '  </SOAP-ENV:Body>'
        + '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

  objHttpReqResp.URL := 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi'
                      + '?callname=' + sCallName
                      + '&siteid=' + sSiteID
                      + '&appid=' + sAppID
                      + '&version=' + sVersion
                      + '&routing=default';

  sResponseBody := TStringStream.Create();
  try
    objHttpReqResp.Execute(sXML, sResponseBody);

    xDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    xDoc.LoadFromStream(sResponseBody);
    xDoc.SaveToFile('XML_Output.txt');

    memHTML.Lines.LoadFromFile('XML_Output.txt');
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');

    memHTML.Lines.Add(objHttpReqResp.URL);
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
  except
    memHTML.Lines.Add('Error happened!');
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
  end;
  sResponseBody.Free;
end;
```

Now the error message is changed as:

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
<faultstring>
  com.ebay.app.pres.service.hosting.WebServiceDisabledException:
  The web service GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest is not properly
  configured or not found and is disabled.
</faultstring>
```

Refer to faltstring and it says "not properly configured". I read eBay Developer Document https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellingManagerSoldListings.html#Request.Pagination.EntriesPerPage but still don't know how to get it configured properly.

Comment: add last line : </SOAP-ENV:Envelope> it "disappeared"  from my answer as i put too little spaces :)

Comment: Also Your URL Should look like: https:// api.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=GetSellingManagerSoldListings&siteid=15&appid=YourAppId&version=945&routing=default (remove space between "https://" and the rest of url )

Comment: Thank you so much, Vancalar. I will try it right now.

Comment: Different error message now:  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
   <faultstring>com.ebay.app.pres.service.hosting.WebServiceDisabledException: The web service eBayAPI is not properly configured or not found and is disabled.</faultstring>
   <detail/>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: By the way, I run program step by step and the URL has not one space between "https://" and the rest. I don't know how it happened.

Comment: https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=861 Check Your URL ! And use EDIT , not comments to provide further details. I Added space here in comments to avoid treating it as a link. You should use link i provided without space and maybe change it for proper environment ( sandbox/production) according to EBAY documentation i posted. Also: use google for God's sake :) The fault string You entered appears in first result!

Comment: @Vancalar
Thank you for your comment. Now I understood more from your advice. I will keep trying with it.

Comment: once again: call is api.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=GetSellingManagerSoldListings&siteid=15&appid=YourAppId&version=945&routing=default   sCallName := 'GetSellingManagerSoldListings'; , not GetSellingManagerSoldListingsREQUEST. Let me know if You succeeded at last

Comment: @Vancalar  SO SO SO great! It works! Thank you so much, Vancalar!. I am a dum programmer, as you already see here. Now I think I can keep going forward for other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like You didn't read carefully [EBAY API documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Concepts/MakingACall.html) and [The web service xxx is not properly
configured or not found and is disabled.](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=861)
according to provide links for SOAP calls.
You put CallName as :

```
sCallName := 'GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest';
```

but it should be:

```
sCallName := 'GetSellingManagerSoldListings';
```

Also i think that instead of try... except You should use try... finally block (or both).

Consider what happens if exception is raised during Your call:

```
 var
    sResponseBody: TStringStream; 
 begin
 ...
 sResponseBody := TStringStream.Create();
    try
     objHttpReqResp.Execute(sXML, sResponseBody);

   xDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
   xDoc.LoadFromStream(sResponseBody);
   xDoc.SaveToFile('XML_Output.txt');

    memHTML.Lines.LoadFromFile('XML_Output.txt');
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');

    memHTML.Lines.Add(objHttpReqResp.URL);
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
except
    memHTML.Lines.Add('Error happened!');
    memHTML.Lines.Add('');
end;
 sResponseBody.Free;
```

this line:

```
 sResponseBody.Free;
```

would never be executed, leading to memory leak...